# Django group by month with possible zeros

Tags: python, django

Am creating an chart for data analytics. So i need to group the count by month for the whole year.

My model:

```
Class Application:
      reference,
      created_at
```

From the above, i need count of applications for each month for the current year. And with the current query i get all the data but i am not getting data for the months which no data is available:

My query:

```
queryset = Application.objects.filter(user=user).annotate(month=TruncMonth('created_at')).values('month').annotate(_applications=Count('id')).order_by('month')
```

For example, If i have data for month `Jan and Feb` the above query gives data of those only but i need the data to contain "0" for all non data available months:

If `March` doesnt have data means, the result should be "0" for that month. How to do this ?

Comment: afaik, the SQL will not do that (correct me if I am wrong). But, I am sure you can do it with Python.

Comment: Am not sure how to do that ! Lol @JPG

Answer (score 0):

You can manually create your dataset using query reqults

```
queryset = Application.objects.filter(user=user).annotate(
    month=TruncMonth('created_at')).values('month').annotate(
    _applications=Count('id')).order_by('month')
applications_by_month = {
    m['month'].month: m['_applications'] for m in queryset
}

dataset = []
year = 2021
for month in range(1, 13):
    dataset.append({
        "month": datetime.date(year=year, month=month, day=1),
        "applications": applications_by_month.get(month, 0)
    })
print(dataset)
```

Output

```
[{'month': datetime.date(2021, 1, 1), 'applications': 0},
 {'month': datetime.date(2021, 2, 1), 'applications': 0},
 {'month': datetime.date(2021, 3, 1), 'applications': 1},
 {'month': datetime.date(2021, 4, 1), 'applications': 0},
 {'month': datetime.date(2021, 5, 1), 'applications': 0},
 {'month': datetime.date(2021, 6, 1), 'applications': 1},
 {'month': datetime.date(2021, 7, 1), 'applications': 0},
 {'month': datetime.date(2021, 8, 1), 'applications': 0},
 {'month': datetime.date(2021, 9, 1), 'applications': 0},
 {'month': datetime.date(2021, 10, 1), 'applications': 0},
 {'month': datetime.date(2021, 11, 1), 'applications': 0},
 {'month': datetime.date(2021, 12, 1), 'applications': 0}]
```